# Unable to map upstream with folder in nginx server

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, winginx

I want to map our system port 82 with 127.0.0.1:8080/runningSite and I am gettting exception with nginx config.

```
upstream dev {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080/runningSite;
}
server {
    rewrite_log on;
    listen [::]:81;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://dev;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }

}
```

Exception :

```
nginx: [emerg] invalid host in upstream "127.0.0.1:8080/runningSite" in C:\nginx -1.8.1/conf/nginx.conf:85
```

Can anyone please help me where I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use location like this

```
location / {
      proxy_pass http://ttbth/home;
      proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
    }
```

Comment: It is throwing me this error
`"proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement, or inside "limit_except" block in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`

Answer (score 6):

You have the URI in the wrong place. It needs to go in the `proxy_pass` and not in the `upstream` block.

Try this:

```
upstream dev {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}
server {
    rewrite_log on;
    listen [::]:81;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://dev/runningSite/;
        proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;          
    }
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.

Comment: thanks for reply. But using this my inner file will be loaded like runningSite/resources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css  is not access able

Comment: This is a great answer when someone want to redirect the uri from `/` to `/dev/blah/blah`, but at the same time you can use a loadbalancer and share the load among nodes. Amazing trick thanks a lot for the tip.

For example:

`upstream dev {
    least_conn;
    server 10.0.0.1:8080;
    server 10.0.0.2:8080;
}`